# How can I add threads to the std::vector<std::thread>

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to fill my vector:

```
...    
auto f = std::bind(&ScheduledExecutor::complete_after, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
threadPoolVector.push_back(std::thread(f, this, delay));
...
```

How can I detach adding thread before push it to the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not detach them. You can use `std::shared_ptr` for threads in vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threadPoolVector;
....
auto f = std::bind(&ScheduledExecutor::complete_after, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
threadPoolVector.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>(f, this, delay));
```

If for some reason you can't use shared pointer, you can use `emplace_back()` vector method for move your thread to vector:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadPoolVector;
...
auto f = std::bind(&ScheduledExecutor::complete_after, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
threadPoolVector.emplace_back(f, this, delay);
```

Comment: But I need to detach them before adding. I have to joing them in destructor of my class.

Comment: If you call join, you should not detach them. detach() called when you can't call join().

Comment: @gomos I wanna run the function compelte_after in new thread. But this function is a private function in my class. So, if I didn't join to the tempThreads, destructor called before all tempThreads are completed.

Comment: @user3818229, I recommend you use shared pointer for store thread objects in vector. When you add thread in shred pointer, the object instance not deleted, only pointer instance. So you do not need detach thread, just call  `threadPoolVector.at(threadIndex)->join()` in destructor of your class.

Answer (score 5):

Using C++11 or higher you can take advantage of **move semantics**. It is better to avoid using pointers, even smart, when they are not absolutely necessary.

You can create `std::thread` object and move it with `std::move` function:

```
std::vector<std::thread> pool;
std::thread th(f);
pool.push_back(std::move(th));
```

You can also use `std::vector::emplace_back` function to create object of `std::thread` directly in `std::vector` instance.

Then you can join or detach them using `for`:

```
for (auto& t : pool)
    t.detach(); // or t.join() to join it
```

or accessing each element using `std::vector::at` or `std::vector::operator[]` functions.